# Spring Security default password configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to config the Spring Security to use a simple password for some endpoints

I added a environment variable in and added it to application properties

`spring.security.user.password=${MyApplicationPassword}`

I want my /admin endpoints to be secured and require this password and the rest to be open. It is a small app and doesn't require some complex security

This is currently my security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.user.password}")
    private String adminPassword;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //"v1" match all my other endpoints beside admin
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/v1/**").permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password(adminPassword)
            .roles("admin")
            .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }
}
```

This configuration doesn't work and gives 403 Forbidden on admin endpoints. I tried to use different approaches with `requestMatchers(admin).authorize`, `csrf.disabled` and without `userDetailsService` and it's the same results - I either secure all endpoints or open them all or get 403 for admin ones.

I tried to search some basic auth methods, but I could only find complex ones with users and roles.

Comment: Remove your `UserDetailsService`, Spring Boot will automatically create the user. You also don't have configuration for anything else besided `v1` which will secure everything else by default.

Comment: So it should use the password from the environment for other endpoints ? Because I still get 403. Could it be a problem of encryption ( smth preseted ) ? I just copied a generated by Spring Security password and pasted it to the environment  like this
"2de58e12-13c0-4e69-864f-555505adbe96"

Comment: Why are you copying passwords? You have already a password specified. I only stated you should remove your `UserDetailsService` nothing more. But as stated you have no config for anything else.

Comment: also, enable spring security DEBUG logs and read the reason for your 403, please learn to debug your application.